# What to do about a tile floor that with globs of thinset

Tags: bathroom, ceramic-tile, thinset

8 months after my general contractors had laid out the new tile on the bathroom floor, I noticed one of my large format tiles starting to wobble.  It got progressively worse so I removed it and discovered that the thinset had not been laid out with an even trowel field.  It was literally 5 globs on each corner and the middle.

It looks like the the same treatment applies to the rest of the floor.  Handyman came in and helped re-set the one tile, but I constantly hear bending and bumping on the floor.  Nightmare?  Not sure if I should ask them to come back or sue if they don't?  Does it ever make sense to apply globs of thinset or were they just inexperienced and or lazy?

Comment: Inexperience or lazy; does the distinction really matter? If the thin-set does not look like the pictures found at https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-install-tile-floor/9ba683603be9fa5395fab909b1ae90d or https://www.lowes.com/n/how-to/install-floor-tile then you have a cob job on your hands. You should call them back but be prepared to fight tooth and nail in getting them to agree to redo the work. You can consider suing out of principle; because the time and money involved can quickly outweigh the cost of the work.

Comment: That method is called "spot bonding" as is absolutely not recommended https://www.ceramictilefoundation.org/blog/eliminate-spot-bonding-ceramic-tile-installation

Answer (score 2):

I've never seen tile installed this way. I've seen installers glob it down, but then trowel it out. Tile needs to be installed on a flat, sound surface or  it will "bend" and will break or loosen over time. what type of guarantees did you get from them? I'd put them on notice and get them out there when the next tile pops off.

Answer (score 2):

Bounce a golf ball all across your floor. You will hear the hollow spots. If your bad tile was not an exception, give the contractor a chance to fix it. He may have been screwed by a bad subcontractor. If he doesn't, get ready to go to the state license board, and maybe small claims court.